# mailx command strange behaviour from cron

Tags: bash, environment-variables, email

I have a script that redirect the df output to a file and then send it in an email.
The mail command is set up as following:

```
/usr/bin/mail -s "Subject" -r from@nowhere.com toaddress@somewhere.com < /tmp/diskSpace.txt
```

Everything is working correctly when I run this script as root user but I have a strange behaviour when I run it from the root crontab.
In this case the message is delivered but the content of /tmp/diskSpace.txt is attached to the email instead to be the body.
I even tried to replicate the root environment running the cron as:

```
env `cat root-env-saved-to-this-file` /bin/bash mailscript.sh
```

but nothing changed.
Any suggestion or I should just handle this with perl mail libraries ?

Comment: What version of the mail command are you using? Mine (bsd-mailx) doesn't have -r as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this before your cron job.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

It will show to cron user where executable directories are.